# Geocoder doesn't work on some of the Android phones

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I am working on Android application which allows user to enter the address and converts to latitude and longitude for further use. I am using following code to get lat and long

```
          addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("11381 zapata ave san diego", 1);

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            double latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
            double longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();

            addGeoFence(latitude, longitude);
            tlFragmentMap.setLatLong(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

This Geocoder works fine on some of the phones only. Can any one suggest me a way to make it work for all the phones. I don't want to use any API. My Compile SDK version is 22, minSdkVErsion is 14 and targetSdkVersion is 22

Comment: Can you give more info, what phones it works well, what phones it doesn't work ?

Comment: @3amoura It worked on Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.1 and din't work on verycool  model SL5000 with Android 4.4.2

Comment: You may first get the standard address by using  `locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
                        getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());` and then use `geocoder.getFromLocationName`. For more details, please refer [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-geocoding-to-get-latitude-longitude-for-an-address/).

Comment: @bjiang I don't have any location prior to this. User enters an address and i use it.

Comment: Yeah, that right, just check [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-geocoding-to-get-latitude-longitude-for-an-address/) the same thing.

Comment: @bjiang Does this works all the time. I heard Android's Geocoder works fine till API 16 only. After that it is hit or miss. Am I correct?

Comment: I tired this after API 16 and it worked fine, you can try it yourself:)

Comment: @bjiang Ok. I will try on both the phones that I have

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work". Did it throw an exception, or just return 0 results?

Answer (score 3):

Use Geocoder's `isPresent()` method to determine whether it is present on current device (this service is not presented in core framework).

More info can be found in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

As a fallback (or may be the only one, because it is guaranteed to work on all devices) solution one can use google's [Geocoding rest API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding)