# Geocoder is not working in android above kitkat version

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I was working with geocoder in my android app to get country name using latitude and longitude. I found that it was working good in kitkat version and below. But when i test my app in above versions it was giving null. So my question is simple that how to use geocoder above kitkat versions.
If there is any other better option instead of geocoder then please suggest me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you acquire runtime permission  for above Api 22 or above ?

Comment: check for run-time permissions and if the problem remains same use Goole Location API to acquire location

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geocoder doesn't work on some of the Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146775/geocoder-doesnt-work-on-some-of-the-android-phones)

Comment: Yes  have added permission but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I post my code for Geocoder. Follow it

```
//Keep this GeocodingLocation.java in a separate file. 

    public class GeocodingLocation {

        private static final String TAG = "GeocodingLocation";
        public static void getAddressFromLocation( final String locationAddress,
                                                  final Context context, final Handler handler) {
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                    String result = null;
                    String latitude = null;
                    String longitude = null;
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
                        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {

                            Log.e("GeocodingLocation --> getAddressFromLocation ==>" +
                                    addressList.toString());

                            Address address = (Address) addressList.get(0);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            latitude = String.valueOf(address.getLatitude());
                            longitude = String.valueOf(address.getLongitude());

                            Logger.infoLog("GeocodingLocation --> Lat & Lang ==>" + latitude +"  "+longitude);
                            //sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
                            //sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Geocoder", e);
                    } finally {
                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        message.setTarget(handler);
                        if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                            message.what = 1;
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("latitude", latitude);
                            bundle.putString("longitude", longitude);
                            message.setData(bundle);
                        } else {
                            message.what = 1;
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                                    "\n Unable to get Latitude and Longitude for this address location.";
                            bundle.putString("address", result);
                            message.setData(bundle);
                        }
                        message.sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
    }
```

call the class from your fragment.

```
private void getAddressLatitudeLongitude(String branchAddress) {
        Log.e("getAddressLatitudeLongitude ==>" + branchAddress);

        GeocodingLocation.getAddressFromLocation(branchAddress, thisActivity, new GeocoderHandler());
    }
```

Keep this class as inner class in same fragment

```
private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:
                    try {
                        Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                        latitude = bundle.getString("latitude");
                        longitude = bundle.getString("longitude");

                        Log.e("CreateBranch --> GeocoderHandler ==>" + latitude + "  " + longitude);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    latitude = null;
                    longitude = null;
            }
            latitudeList.add(latitude);
            longitudeList.add(longitude);

            if(latitude==null || longitude==null){
                showAlertDialog("Please enter correct address", Constants.APP_NAME);
            }

            Log.e("Latitude list =>" + latitudeList);
            Log.e("Longitude list =>" + longitudeList);
        }
    }
```

Output will get latitude and longitude. Hope this answer helps.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I am not asking to get latitude and longitude from address. I am asking to get location address from latitude and longitude.